# Compare datetime on javascript converting them to unixtime

Tags: javascript

I have two variables formated like this

```
2017-09-27 16:26:39

2017-09-28 06:30:00
```

Comment: hmmm what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Comment: Please include some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"?  Are you trying to decide if they represent the same time?  Do you want to know which one is earlier?  Do you want to know the number of milliseconds between them?  As others have said, show your code.

Comment: String comparison like: `'2017-09-27 16:26:39' < '2017-09-28 06:30:00'` works too in this dateformat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Date.parse` to convert your variables to unix timestamps. Then you could compare the two timestamps like as follows.

```js
var unixtimeOne = Date.parse("2017-09-27 16:26:39");
var unixtimeTwo = Date.parse("2017-09-28 06:30:00");

console.log(unixtimeOne);
console.log(unixtimeTwo);
  
// You could compare the timestamps as follows
console.log(unixtimeOne < unixtimeTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var date1 = new Date('2017 09-27 16:26:39');
    var date2 = new Date('2017-09-28 06:30:00');

    var msecs1 = date1.getTime(); // in milliseconds
    var msecs2 = date2.getTime(); // in milliseconds

    console.log(msecs1 - msecs2); // -50601000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use moment.js, it gives you great comparison methods such as 'isSame', 'isAfter' and 'isBefore':

```
var x = moment('2017-09-27 16:26:39');
var y = moment('2017-09-28 06:30:00');

x.isSame(y) //false
x.isAfter(y) //false
x.isBefore(y) //true
```

To find the time difference between the two datetimes:

```
y.diff(x, 'hours') //14
```